# Arquillian REST ClassNotFoundException org.jboss.resteasy.logging.Logger

Tags: java, wildfly, resteasy, jboss-arquillian

When running my Arquillian REST test I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` for `org.jboss.resteasy.logging.Logger`.

I noticed that the problem started happening when I started using the JSON parser in my test, but I can't find the relation.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class PetResourceTest {

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("wildfly-ds.xml").addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addPackage(PetResource.class.getPackage());
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void testPost(@ArquillianResteasyResource final WebTarget webTarget) {
        final Response response = webTarget.path("/pet").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.json(new Pet()));

        Long idExpected = 1L;
        Long id = response.readEntity(Long.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(idExpected, id);

    }

}
```

My Arquillian dependencies are:

```
<project>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-rest-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-rest-client-impl-3x</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The complete error stack is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/logging/Logger
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.<clinit>(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:46)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.initDefaultEngine(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:306)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:48)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.extension.rest.client.RestEnricher.enrichByType(RestEnricher.java:45)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.extension.rest.client.BaseRestEnricher.resolve(BaseRestEnricher.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.enrichArguments(LocalTestExecuter.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:372)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:246)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:260)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:324)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.execute(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.on(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:317)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:205)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:219)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.logging.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 126 more
```

Comment: suppose there is a dependency conflict with `org.jboss.resteasy.logging.Logger`. you will need to exclude few dependecies in your `pom.xml` .If you are using eclipse just analyse the dependency hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arquillian will use version `3.0.0` of `resteasy-client`.

As suggested by Rajith in the comments, I've excluded that dependency from `arquillian-rest-client-impl-3x` and added a new one with newer version, and it worked just fine.

```
<project>

    <!-- ... -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-rest-client-impl-3x</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ... -->

</project>
```

Comment: I tried to apply the same solution but now I am having issues with the client.   javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: com.vdms.bookstore.model.Book